# Last letter not getting set while onChange event

Tags: reactjs, onchange, use-state

I'm trying to write a function for a live search filter, this is what I have for doing that:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    text: ''
});

<Input name="text" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} type={'text'} className="form-control"></Input>

const handleChange = async e=>{
    const {name, value} = e.target;

    await setValues({
        ...values,
        [name]: value
    });

    console.log(values);


    CallAPIWithSearchText(value.text);
}
```

The main problem is that for example; if I type **"hello"** what is stored in my const is **"hell"** and if I remove all text I'm getting **"h"** instead of null/empty string.

What can I do to fix my code?

Comment: `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. You can pass the `e.target.value` to `CallAPIWithSearchText`.

Comment: @HassanImam I think that what you're saying makes the trick! I'm sending directly the value const and handling in my CallAPI function if param is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with your `setValues` function. It **doesn't** return a `Promise`. So, you can't use `async-await` with it.

What can you can do is, use the `useEffect` hook like below:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react' //Import the useEffect hook.

useEffect(()=>{
  //This function will run every time the value of values state changes.
  console.log(values); //Will give you the updated value of values state.
  CallAPIWithSearchText(value.text); // Call your api method
  //Do some other stuff
}, [values])

const CallAPIWithSearchText = (text) => {
  //Use text as per your need.
  if(text === '') // Show all results
  else
    //Show results as per text
}

const handleChange = e => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;

    setValues({ //No need to use await
        ...values,
        [name]: value
    });
}
```

Comment: I already have one useEffect to call CallAPIWithSearchText where I'm sending null value to search all values, if I add this [values] my function is going to be executed always that state change?

Comment: So basically if values.text == '', then you want to show all values, right?

Comment: Yep. I want to call my API in this way: api?searchValue="" or api?searchValue=Hello

Comment: I have edited my answer. So now, every time the values state changes, the useEffect is going to run. So, if values.text is == '', then you can show all results & if not, show results related to values.text

Answer (score 0):

In React [state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so you can use [the effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to solve this problem.

Every time your state changes, the callback in the effect hook runs after the render:

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.4/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="react">

const {useEffect, useState} = React;

function CallAPIWithSearchText (text) {
  console.log('API called with', text);
}

function Example () {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({text: ''});

  const handleChange = async e => {
    const {value} = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      text: value,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(values);
    const {text} = values;
    if (text) CallAPIWithSearchText(text);
  }, [values]);

  return (
    <input
      name="text"
      onChange={handleChange}
      type={'text'}
      className="form-control"
      value={values.text}
    ></input>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```